# Adding multiple pointers of the same type to vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have an vector of pointers in which i want to store pointers to objects of same type

`Parent * tempParent=new Parent();`

```
vector<Parent *> parents;
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
  tempParent.setAge(i);
  parents.push_back(tempParent);
}
```

What this does it sets all parents age to 8. Any ideas how could I make them point to a different objects so that they all have different age?
Thanks

Comment: What is `tempParent`?

Comment: it's an pointer to parent object

Comment: You just added nine pointers that all points to the same `Parent` object into the vector. (Owning raw pointers and naked `new`s are terrible anyway. Use a vector of smart pointers, or even better, of `Parent`s.)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store 9 `Parent` objects in a `std::vector` then you need to create 9 of them.

You have multiple solution to the problem, you can just store plain objects (and not pointers, since you don't have to store pointers if you don't need them), eg:

```
std::vector<Parent> parents;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
  parents.push_back(Parent(i)); // assuming a Parent::Parent(int age) constructor
}
```

If you really want pointers you need to call `new` 9 times by sure:

```
std::vector<Parent*> parents;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
  Parent* parent = new Parent(i);
  parents.push_back(parent);
}
```

Mind that if you really need pointers wrapping them inside an `unique_ptr` is a good idea if the vector has ownership on them:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> parents;
parents.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Parent>(new Parent(age));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 9 different objects of `Parent` so they will point to 9 different object.I think this code will help you :

```
vector<Parent *> parents;
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    Parent * tempParent=new Parent();
    tempParent->setAge(i);
    parents.push_back(tempParent);
}
```